# Can I secure an API against multiple identity providers?

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an ASP.NET Web API with no user authentication serving two client apps.

The only reason this has been fine is because the API is not open to the public but only accessible to the IP addresses of those two apps.

Now there's a plan to open up the API to the internet. This means I need to secure it properly. Looks like OAuth2 and OpenID Connect are the way to go.

The problem is the client apps are authenticating against different identity providers, one is using Azure AD, the other using Azure AD B2C from a different directory.

Can this work with OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at this API sample which accepts AAD and AAD B2C tokens.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/spa-hellojs/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC